# render UICollectionViewCell snapshot to another UIImage control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

**Unwanted** result: a entirely black snapshot.

**Wanted**: a snapshot of the collectionview cell contents.
Using: *snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:*

I have a task of dropping an image of a rendered cell from a UICollectionView into a UIImage of another view. It seems fairly straightforward, but i am showing only a black image. I wondered if anyone had any pointers. This seems to *almost* work as the resulting black image is sized as per the cell itself, so something is happening at least partially correct:’

Within the view with the UICollectionView, responding to a cell tap:

```
UICollectionViewCell *tappedCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *cellSnapshot = [tappedCell snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES]; // << no difference
//UIView *cellSnapshot1 = [tappedCell.contentView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Then the detail view is displayed and the snapshot is passed as follows:

```
if (cellSnapshot) {
    detailViewController.snapshot = cellSnapshot;  // << cellSnapshot is a UIView
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Then on loading the detail view, the image is set into a button as follows:

```
[self.myButton setImage:[self imageWithView:_snapshot]];
```

And imageWithView is defined as:

```
-(UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

The result: a black image only.  the lldb shows the snapshot as a _UIReplicantView with a nil _layer. I must be missing something obvious. The image will be white if `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f)` has the view.opaque to NO.

All thoughts are welcome! thank you.

Comment: I have walked through numerous SO questions as well, and see a few references to "black images" as well, but no clear solution. Others seem to suggest the methodology works, but perhaps the collectionview cell has something within it that keeps it from rendering? Perhaps because it is a repeating element?

I could not find much to explain what is meant by _UIReplicantView which is what the snapshot appears to be.

Comment: Well this didn't elicit much attention ;)